# How to create a slope chart using vega-lite

Tags: visualization, vega-lite

I wanted to create a slope chart which has 2 quantitative axis which are total tests and total confirmed covid-19 cases. Each country is a line connecting two axis. I have created a slope chart, but it is not my desired slope chart.

https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/imdevskp/corona-virus-report
Above is the dataset link which I obtain the data from.
This is my code below:

```
    {
    "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
    "data": {"url": "worldometer_data.csv"},
    "title": { "text": "Slope chart showing the total tests and total covid-19 cases for each country"         },
    "mark": "line",
    "encoding": {
      "y": {
        "field": "Country/Region",
        "type": "nominal"
      },
      "x": {
        "field": "TotalTests",
        "type": "quantitative"
      },
      "x2": {
        "field": "TotalCases",
        "type": "quantitative"
      },
      "color": {
        "field": "Continent",
        "type": "nominal"
      }
    }
  }
```

Below is my output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzW9G.png)